# Logistic Regression - Conversion of variables

Tags: regression, logistic

I have as dataset where I got independent (X-Variables) in different versions which need to be converted/transform so that an logistics regression can be run. I am new to L.regression and don't understand how to structure variables so that it can be used.
Dataset can be download from here:
https://ufile.io/apxl0n75

[image]

Comment: I do not see a way to transform your posted data set into a format that can be run through a logistic regression (or any other kind of regression or machine learning model).

Comment: @Dave Dataset can be downloaded from the link in the question.

Comment: This spreadsheet is not a dataset, it looks more like a codebook just showing the possible levels for each so called "X-variable". Technically speaking, you don't have to do a damn thing to your variables to run the model. Have  you tried it?

Comment: @AdamO Yes, you are correct that was the summarised data. Not the dataset. I have uploaded the correct dataset now. Please check and advice.